# Rename and increment on duplicate

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a series of image files with filename formats as follows.

```
9407-C-9406-B-038.jpg
9407-C-9406-B-118.jpg
9422-AC-012.jpg
9422-AC-112.jpg
9422-BD-043.jpg
9422-BD-Still-001.jpg
9405_M.jpg
9792A.jpg
9792B.jpg
```

The relevant portion for my purpose is the first 4 characters, the rest is irrelevant.

I'd like to rename the files such that the leading 4 char string is retained, the extension is retained, but the rest is incremented when a duplicate is encountered : 
e.g :

```
9422-AC-012.jpg becomes 942200.jpg
9422-AC-112.jpg becomes 942201.jpg
9422-BD-043.jpg becomes 942202.jpg
9422-BD-Still-001.jpg becomes 942203.jpg
9405_M.jpg becomes 940500.jpg
9792A.jpg becomes 979200.jpg
9792B.jpg becomes 979201.jpg
```

Using 'rename' I can strip the string after the first 4 chars, and I can increment in totality, which results with the incremental portion of the filename ending up in the thousands.

`rename -n  -N 0001 's/(?<=.{4}).*/$N.jpg/' *.jpg`

Can anyone suggest a way to strip the filename after the first 4 chars, rename the file, and increment only when a duplicate is encountered?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

With the filenames listed in file

```
$ while read f t; 
  do 
     echo "mv $f $t"; 
  done < <(awk -F\. '{k=substr($0,1,4); printf "%s\t%s%04d.%s\n", $0,k,a[k]++,$NF}' file)

mv 9407-C-9406-B-038.jpg 94070000.jpg
mv 9407-C-9406-B-118.jpg 94070001.jpg
mv 9422-AC-012.jpg 94220000.jpg
mv 9422-AC-112.jpg 94220001.jpg
mv 9422-BD-043.jpg 94220002.jpg
mv 9422-BD-Still-001.jpg 94220003.jpg
mv 9405_M.jpg 94050000.jpg
mv 9792A.jpg 97920000.jpg
mv 9792B.jpg 97920001.jpg
```

remove `echo` for the actual renaming, assumes no white space in the file name, at least 4 chars long and has extension.

the example shows two digit counter, you mentioned the counter to be in the thousands, here it's controlled by the print format `%04d`, change 4 to 2 if you don't expect more than 100.  Regardless, the counter will create unique file but may extend from the allocated number of digits (e.g. it will generate 00,01,..99, and for the next one will be 100.)